# C Character Replace in One Line

Tags: c, string, while-loop

I've been learning about some of the clever C functions that require a loop, but no loop body to execute (like `strcpy()`), and so are only one line long.

Just out of interest, is there any way to reduce the replacement of all `\n` newline characters with spaces to one line like this?

At the moment I've got

```
char* newline_index;
while (newline_index = strchr(file_text, '\n'))
{
    *newline_index = ' ';
}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
while (*strchr(file_text, '\n') = ' ');
```

but of course when strchr returns null I'll try to dereference a null pointer.

I know using strchr is cheating, because it contains more code, but I'd like to see if there's a one line way to do this just using standard c functions.

---

Edit: With some help, this is the best I've come up with:

```
char* newline_index;
while ((newline_index = strchr(file_text, '\n')) && (*newline_index = ' '))
```

Comment: If the file is big, then it will be VERY SLOW to do it, `strchr` scan the file, so it will take time to scan the file again and again instead of scanning it once.

Comment: This is true, but remember that my aim is being concise, not speed.

Comment: You want something like this: 


char* newline_index;
while ((newline_index = *strchr(file_text, '\n')) && (newline_index != NULL) && (newline_index = ' '));

??

Comment: Ah that's a clever use of &&,but it's still effectively two lines (using a semicolon means you should have a newline really.

Comment: I think the dereference should later though, to avoid crashes:
while ((newline_index = strchr(file_text, '\n')) && (newline_index != NULL) && (*newline_index = ' '));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the following code. The following code is in One line and it avoid the call of the function `strchr()`:

```
char* p = file_text;
while(*p!='\0' && (*p++!='\n' || (*(p-1) = ' ')));
```

You can also use the `for` loop:

```
char* p;
for(p = file_text; *p!='\0' && (*p!='\n' || (*p = ' ')); p++);
```

---

For the solution you provide:

```
char* newline_index;
while ((newline_index = strchr(file_text, '\n')) && (*newline_index = ' '))
```

Calling `strchr()` in this way will make the search start from the beginning of your `file_text` each time you want to search for the `'\n'`.

I suggest to change it to:

```
char* newline_index = file_text;
while ((newline_index = strchr(newline_index, '\n')) && (*newline_index = ' '))
```

this will allow to `strchr()` to continue the search of the `'\n'` from the last position and not from the beginning.

And even with that optimisation the calling of the `strchr()` function take time also. So that's why I proposed a solution without calling the `strchr()` function

Comment: +1, the first suggestion is faster when the lines are short (and on my machine, which has unoptimized `strchr`).

Comment: +1 Great suggestion on optimizing what I had. But mainly I like this answer because you managed to do it without function calls.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly efficient and simple way to do it:

```
for(char *p = file_text; (p = strchr(p, '\n')); *p = ' ')
    ;
```

Comment: Note that declaring `p` into the `for` loop is not portable for all gcc

Comment: @MOHAMED: It's legal C99, and should be accepted by any recent compiler except MSVC.

Comment: +1 This *is* a very good suggestion. Definitely the simpler option, and it does avoid running strchr from the start as I had.